# Use and Convert Array into JSON

Tags: json

I have this array

```
["123", "456", "789", "0"]
```

And I would like to build a JSON out of its values.

Expected result is

```
    {
  "list": [
    {
      "code": 123
    },
    {
      "code": 456
    },
    {
      "code": 789
    },
    {
      "code": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I work this structure in javascript? Thank u for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a loop and a JS variable that writes it that way then JSON.Stringify it out once complete.... I.e.

```
var json = { list: [] };
for(i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
  json.list.push( { code : arr[i] } );
}
var stringOutput = JSON.Stringify(json)
```

Note: not tried to compile or run the code but that should be close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner you can do the following:

`let result = {"list": ["123", "456", "789", "0"].map((code) => { return {"code":code} })};`

Or to break out the steps and to use older syntax:

```
var orig = ["123", "456", "789", "0"];

var list = orig.map(function(code) {
    return {"code": code};
});

var result = {"list": list};
```